# How can I adjust the music in imovie for part of a movie?

Tags: macos, audio, music, imovie, video-editing

I have a imovie project that I am creating and I have video clips and an audio track which plays a song.  I see that I can adjust the volume level of the song for the whole song but I want to lower the volume for part of the song (because I want to emphasize the audio coming from the video clip)

Is it possible to adjust the volume of a music track for part of the song in imovie?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd>-click on the volume adjustment to create new keyframes
2. Adjust the volume between these keyframes by dragging.

[image]